# My custom Drupal site is not resolving the URI correctly

Tags: php, mysql, iis, drupal, drupal-7

I am new to Drupal and this is my first time using it.

I have a site that uses Drupal running in production environment. I like to copy the production copy over and attempt to make changes to it for testing/learning.

Anyway, to get started I setup a new installation of Drupal 7 on Windows IIS 7.5. After completed the installation and got it to running, I renamed the folder "sites" to "sitesORG".

Then from my production server I took a copy of the "sites" folder and placed it into the new Drupal installation on my local machine.

Now my local machine has the folder called "sites" and inside of it I see the following 3 folders"
1) All
2) Default
3) myProject

From my production box, I took mysql dump and restored it in a new database called "abc" on my localhost

I opened the setting file in "myProject" folder and change the databases connection to a databases on the local machine and changed the database name to "abc"

Then I go through and update my script using http://localhost/acquia-drupal7/

Now, when I got to the very first page, I don't get any colors/pictures. I get a white page with text. It looks like the css files/images are not being rendered correctly.

On the same page there is a link titled "Click Here To login" when I click it I got to the following URL http://localhost/user instead of "http://localhost/acquia-drupal7/user"

There is something that is not being mapped correctly. What could be causing my issues? How can I get the css/images file and the URL to be corrected?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your `settings.php` file, you need to uncomment and update the `$base_url` variable with the following value: `"http://localhost/acquia-drupal7"`.

Then, depending if your windows setup allows you to use `.htaccess` or not, you would need to uncomment the `RewriteBase /drupal` and change the value to `RewriteBase /acquia-drupal7`. If you are using standard IIS configurations, you would need to apply the same logic.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added `$base_url = 'http://localhost/acquia-drupal7';` to both settings.php file in `default` and in `myProject` but that did not work. What .htaccess file are you referring too? I don't have a .htaccess file in the `myProject` folder

Comment: @MikeA in the root directory of Drupal, where index.php file is located, Drupal includes an .htaccess file. I'm not familiar with your Windows installation so I'm not so sure if changing it will do anything because usually with IIS you need to set those configurations yourself.

Comment: Let me ask you a question. How can I tell if my environment is setup to host multiple sites or one site only?

Comment: I got rid of IIS. I run XAMPP on another machine. I install a fresh instance of Drupal. I copied the "myProject" site and into `F:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites`  How to I get the main instance to point to `myProject`?

Comment: @MikeA You need to rename `myProject` to your actual domain name. If you are using XAMPP I believe you must have used a domain name like `mylocaldrupal.com`, so you would just need to rename `myProject` to `mylocaldrupal.com`. You can read more about that [here](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site).

Comment: Really I only have 1 site which is "myProject" do I really need 2 domains to get this project setup?   I added a file called `sites.php` in my sites directory what contains the following `$sites['test.example.com'] = 'myProject';` but the project does not seem to know how to point the domain to the correct project